# How to define (using php or jquery) the width of a div to fit the width + margin of the anchor tags inside?

Tags: css, width

I want the width of `.nivo-controlNav` to automatically fit the width + margin of `.nivo-controlNav a`

code:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    margin: 480px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    background: url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

Comment: seems like you really want to automate the centering of the .nivo-controlNav

Comment: @kjy112 It became an obsession.

Comment: there's a github repo on nivo-slider if i remember correctly. maybe you want to try there as well. https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it:

```
// calculate outerWidth of .nivo-controlNav
    var customWidth = $j('.nivo-controlNav a').outerWidth(true);
    // Returns the number of matched elements
    var customNumber = $j('.nivo-controlNav a').size();
    $j('.nivo-controlNav').css("width", customWidth*customNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you ask, but you can use jquery [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var customWidth = $('.nivo-controlNav a').outerWidth(true);
 $('.nivo-controlNav').css("width",customWidth);
});
```

Comment: I think this is the way, but the width just became 25px. There are like 5 buttons of 22px so it should be 110px.

Comment: try this: after images are loaded get the total width of the .nivo-controlNav and use that width to center it against the .slider width (which is the total width of the slider), then adjust the position using left: in the css of .nivo-controlNav

Comment: @janoChen  a has width:22px & margin-right:3px, a total of 25px; this is what outerWidth calculate. What do you need?

Comment: @kjy112 Sounds good, how would be that in code (sorry I'm a bit jQuery aliterated) ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well, I need the total width + margin of all the .nivo-controlNav a (they are 5 now but the number may vary).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just tell `.nivo-controlNav` to `float:left`? It sounds like you're using a framework of some kind, and this might need some working around, but it seems a lot more stable than using JavaScript.